# SSRS compare date to see which is greater

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create an IIF statement which uses 0 if the `endDate` is less than the `reportStartDate`

Thus far I've tried

```
=Sum(IIf(Parameters!reportStartDate.Value <= DateValue(Fields!endDate), Field!someValue, 0))
```

but this throws an error message when I attempt to save it

```
Value of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field' cannot be converted to 'String'.
```

Comment: you have to convert this (Parameters!reportStartDate.Value) to DateTime first.

Comment: `Fields!endDate` and `Field!someValue` should be `Fields!endDate.Value` and `Field!someValue.Value` respectively.